# Translate from a language to English on the console

Tags: bash, google-translate, lynx, elinks

I work with in a company with various other languages to my own (English) and so I use https://translate.google.com a reasonable amount, but as I am on the terminal a lot, I would find a lot of convenience in being able to do that there than having to open a new google tab. The URL structure is trivial, and this works if put into any browser https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=bonjour&op=translate, replace `fr` by any source language and `en` by any target language and `bonjoun%20mon%20ami` by any word/phrase. Ideally, I would like 2x functions in bash:

```
tt (translate to), tt <target-lang> <English word or phrase to translate to target-lang>
tf (translate from), tf <source-lang> <word or phrase to translate to English>
```

I have tried for a few days without success with `lynx`, `elinks` etc and many searches on commandlinefu and other sites (e.g. https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/translate-english/dHJhbnNsYXRlIGVuZ2xpc2g=/sort-by-votes), but not found the trick to returning the translated text. Are Google blocking things somehow, and is there a workaround - surely some tool (`lynx`, `elinks`, `links2`) can  resolve the text being sent back when we hit the URL, and then we can extract just the translated text using `sed`, `cut`, `grep` etc?

If this is being blocked by cookies or some sign-on requirements, are there alternative console tools or sites to Google Translate that would allow other translation services?

Comment: There is a tool `translate-shell` at least in Ubuntu.

Comment: This might help: [Best Command Line Language Translators for Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/command-line-language-translators-for-linux/)

Comment: These are vastly superior to what I was wanting to do by poking at the Google Translate URL. I see that `translate-shell` is immediately available from `apt` and `dnf` repositories, *and* it can also display dictionary definitions (something else that is of use to me, e.g. `trans -d dog`). If I want to construct `tt` / `tf` as alises or functions I can also construct them easily using `trans`. Thanks for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various translation services have an API, Google Translate has an API, Deepl has an API. I find some are more accurate than others, but this is a matter of personal preference.

https://www.deepl.com/docs-api

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate

If you want to use it from shell, it is easy enough to cobble a small bash script with `curl` and `jq` to process the JSON responses, or better, use Python or Perl which supports all these operations natively.